# Grouping, counting and selecting on R dataset

Tags: r, count, grouping

I have a dataset like this:

```
x
       A      B
1      x      2
2      y      4
3      z      4
4      x      4
5      x      4
6      x      3
......
```

I want to know if in this dataset are present a same number of "A" upper than some value(for example 3).

Probably i will need to group this value in a temporary table getting this:

```
  X    Y     z
  4    1     1
```

and after this i will call another method (that i don't know) that gives me this result

X

because only the value X is present more than 3 times in my previous table.
Can R optimise this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> data<-data.frame(factor(c("x","y","z","x","x","x")),c(2,4,4,4,4,3))

To get the count of each letter, do

> table(data[,1])

and to get the name of the factors with > 3

> names(table(data[,1]))[table(data[,1]) > 3]

Answer (score 1):

Don´t know if I understand you right... whats with this B column?

Is this working for you?

```
set.seed(1234)
A <- sample(c("x", "y", "z"), 20, replace = TRUE)
Ad <- data.frame(table(A))
with(Ad, A[Freq >= 7])
      [1] x y
```

Comment: B column for my purpose is nothing

Comment: I don't thik that your solution can be useful for me.
My data frame can be grouped using table() function, so i will get a result like this:

x  y  z
4  2  2

but after that i need to get the column value(almost is 0 or 1 value that match this condition) with occurrence >= 3(for example), in this case only x is the result.

Comment: I understand, this statements seems works fine for me, i thought there was a specific command for it, but this should works well for me. Thanks